# Different unique and partition key in CosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, sharding, unique-key

We are moving from MongoDB to CosmosDB. In MongoDB, we never created any partition key because everything was working fine . But in CosmosDB, because of effective use of RUs, we need to create partition keys.

Now the problem is that we already have a compound unique key in our collection which we do not want to use as partition key (also I am not sure if compound partition key is possible in cosmosDB or not) because we do not search usually using this unique key but we use some other parameters.

Is it somehow possible to create partition key which is different from unique key?

I tried to do so but I always get error -

```
cannot create unique index over { abc : 1.0, xyz : 1.0} with shard key pattern { partitionKey : 1.0 }
```

I also tried to create partition key which is a subset of unique key but that also results in the same error.

Is there a solution to this problem or someone knows a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create `unique` index for **sharded collection** this way:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "abc" : 1, "xyz" : 1, "partitionKey" : 1 }, {unique:true})
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#creating-unique-indexes)

Comment: That also does not work (which I tried earlier also) but your answer forced me to try it once more and finally I got it. In index creation query, partitionKey should be the first field. So, the query you mentioned does not work but following query works (strange) -  db.collection.createIndex( { "partitionKey" : 1 ,"abc" : 1, "xyz" : 1}, {unique:true}). Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @N.. post your own response, could help other users